# category() got an unexpected keyword argument 'category_name_slug'

Tags: python, django

I'm a beginner with django and was trying out the Tango with Django tutorial. But I'm getting an inscrutable error which I've not been able to rectify. I get the following error:

```
TypeError at /rango/category/python/
category() got an unexpected keyword argument 'category_name_slug'
```

The debug error is being shown as contained in not the app files but in the core django handler files as below:

```
Exception Type: TypeError
Exception Value:    
category() got an unexpected keyword argument 'category_name_slug'
Exception Location: c:\virtualenv\rango\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py in get_response, line 111
```

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse
from rango.models import Category
from rango.models import Page

def index(request):
    category_list_likes = Category.objects.order_by('-likes')[:5]
    category_list_views = Category.objects.order_by('-views')[:5]
    context_dict = {
        'categories_likes': category_list_likes,
        'categories_views': category_list_views,
    }
    return render(request, 'rango/index.html', context_dict)

def about(request):
    return render(request, 'rango/about.html')

def category(request, category_name_url):
    context_dict = {}
    try:
        category = Category.objects.get(slug=category_name_slug)
        context_dict['category_name'] = category.name
        pages = Page.objects.filter(category=category)
        context_dict['pages'] = pages
        context_dict['category'] = category
    except Category.DoesNotExist:
        pass
    return render(request, 'rango/category.html', context_dict)
```

models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.template.defaultfilters import slugify

class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128, unique=True)
    views = models.IntegerField(default=0, unique=False)
    likes = models.IntegerField(default=0, unique=False)
    slug = models.SlugField(unique=True)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.slug = slugify(self.name)
        super(Category, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name

class Page(models.Model):
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    url = models.URLField()
    views = models.IntegerField(default=0, unique=False)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.title
```

urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, url
from rango import views

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
    url(r'about/', views.about, name = 'About'),
    url(r'category/(?P<category_name_slug>[\w\-]+)/$', views.category, name='category'),)
```

admin.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from rango.models import Category, Page

class PageAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('title', 'category', 'url')

class CategoryAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('name', 'views', 'likes')
    prepopulated_fields = {'slug':('name',)}

admin.site.register(Category, CategoryAdmin)
admin.site.register(Page, PageAdmin)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `category()` view expects the `category_name_url` parameter:

```
def category(request, category_name_url):
    ...
```

But in the `urls.py` your define the `category_name_slug` parameter:

```
url(r'category/(?P<category_name_slug>[\w\-]+)/$', views.category,
                                                   name='category'),
```

Make the parameter equal in both places.  For example:

```
def category(request, slug):
    ...
```

But in the `urls.py` your define the `category_name_slug` parameter:

```
url(r'category/(?P<slug>[\w\-]+)/$', views.category, name='category'),
```

Comment: Thanks! I realised the error in the argument. But after making the changes and adding `category_name_slug` both in views.py and urls.py, I'm still getting the following error.`Exception Value: category() got an unexpected keyword argument 'category_name_slug'
Exception Location: c:\virtualenv\rango\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py in get_response, line 111`
What I also don't understand is why the exception is being raised in the virtualenv django core file.

Comment: Reload the server. Exception is raised exactly in the place where it occurs - django tries to call your view with the wrong keyword argument.

Comment: There was an issue with the url regex code. Changed the `url(r'category/(?P<slug>[\w\-]+)/$', views.category, name='category'),` to `url(r'^category/(?P<slug>[\w\-]+)/$', views.category, name='category'),`
Thanks a lot man!

Answer (score 2):

You should change your url definition to:

```
url(r'category/(?P<slug>[\w\-]+)/$', views.category, name='category')
```